Enabling CSS LINK element doesn't trigger load event
I am enhancing vite-plugin-single-spa.  Specifically, I am working issue #120.  The PR I have ready pretty much works but I had to take into account something very unexpected in my eyes:  A disabled CSS LINK element triggers a network call when re-enabled (which I find OK), but never fires the load event, which is the part I'm not OK with.
A reproduction can be found here, where I used a simple Svelte project to showcase.  I could not create a more minimal reproduction because not every CSS link that gets re-enabled triggers a network call.  I am guessing this behavior is completely controlled by the cache policy applied to the content.  For example, importing Bootstrap from JSDelivr doesn't trigger a network call when the link element is re-enabled:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

So a regular Vite + Svelte project that imports a CSS file from its /public folder works for the demo:  The load event never fires.
My question here since I'm no HTML expert:  Am I in the wrong thinking that if there's a network call there should always be a load event?  Furthermore:  If I'm correct about how the need for a network call is determined, how could I know if a network call will be made?  My use case in vite-plugin-single-spa would need to know this.


Setting the disabled property in the DOM causes the stylesheet to be removed from the document's Document.styleSheets list.


Note: The load event fires once the stylesheet and all of its imported content has been loaded and parsed, and immediately before the styles start being applied to the content.

MDN 

It's possible to add a query string to a CSS file request and change that to invalidate the cache, if you want to try to force it to reload a file.

If you'd like to trigger a load event on a link element you can do
const linkEl = document.querySelector('link[rel=stylesheet]')

const loadEv = new Event('load')

linkEl.dispatchEvent(loadEv)

If you want to trigger a load event each time the stylesheet is enabled or disabled and for some reason can't just do so in the regular event handler that's modifying the value of disabled (e.g., not yours), an observer could be used. Modifying the MDN example we would get something like:
const targetNode = document.querySelector('link[rel=stylesheet])

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true }

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'disabled') {
      // ... fire load event
    }
  }
}

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);


// If or when necessary, stop observing
observer.disconnect();


Interesting for sure.  Indeed, I could modify the query string to trigger the download, but that's undesirable:  It's a performance hit users should not suffer.  While ingenious, it doesn't cut it.  The other piece, on the other hand, seems great!  To dispatch the event using an observer is super helpful to me because I already am observing.  Conclusion:  Even though this is not the answer for my question, it is very helpful and deserves the green check.  Many thanks.

Oops.  Apologies.  On second thought:  While this does trigger the load event every time disabled changes, this serves me no good:  The purpose of the code is to prevent FOUC, and simply raising the event after re-enabling the stylesheet is meaningless:  I need  the load event to trigger after the potential re-download.  My mistake.  Still, I liked your proposed answer a lot.

No problem. I've been screwing around with a custom SPA implementation, so this was not far off base though IDK Svelte/Vite, lol. Can you specify what you mean by potential re-download? For example I'm fetching a minimal HTML fragment with link + script tags included and injecting it with innerHTML, then thatElement.querySelectorAll the link and script tags and passing them on to be removed from the dynamically loaded element and injected into the document (so that the CSS and JS are actually run). Here, if they already exist on doc they're ignored, else they're loaded (locally tho).

An observer may be able to watch the children of doc for added style/link, and trigger the load event, but IDK how to tell if one was already triggered. Svelte may already be doing something along these lines, so it'd likely be well worth a deep dive into the source to check. Backup thought would be to use the Fetch API or XMLHTTPRequest (deprecated, but if necessary for older browsers and a fetch poly-fill is unrealistic) with a Proxy wrapper.

Basically:  The browser may check with the server about a new version of the stylesheet after its disabled property is removed.  That's it.  So that's a network call.  I just wanted a load event that would trigger after that network call finished.  Just like that.  Sometimes, a network call doesn't happen, and sometimes it happens.  I was hoping to use the load/error events to determine when the download happened to avoid FOUC.  This is why an artificially raised event is meaningless.

Based on HTML stylesheet spec, it seems if the style is disabled on load it will wait to fetch it until it is not disabled, and if it has already been fetched it would only do so again based on the caching policy for the given resource, which can be modified by headers. Default cache behavior and most CDN would of course prefer caching non-HTML resources to limit network usage.

Thanks, I've read all that.  That's not my case. The LINK element, when created, is created in an enabled state and the load/error events work as expected.  When a MFE is unloaded, the associated LINK elements get disabled; if the MFE is loaded again, then the LINK elements (pre-existing ones) get re-enabled.  This might trigger a network call.  this network call doesn't have an associated load event.
